# Issue opening an app from browser on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I'm trying to let people open mobile apps from my website and I found url scheme of some app for it like fb:// , twitter:// , .v.v.

They're all work fine ( with window.location.replace() or document.location.href ...) on IOS devices only; when on Android devices, nothing happened. I knew that Android app has another way to do it, not those same url scheme like for IOS, so anyone who has achieved it on Android for any app please help me ! I couldn't find any official url of an Android app to be opened from web browser yet.

Answer (score 0):

On Android you can do it by creating your own url scheme and using **Deep Links**.

This is the official documentation explaining how to create and use them:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking